# How to increase google crawl my sitemap speed?

Tags: google

I am now building my site but I don't know why the speed crawl my sitemap too slowly. 
My sitemap was added 1 month ago, but now google only index (400/500 urls) for website.
and in the column (in right side) for mobile sitemap, google not yet index any!

Please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you change your crawl rate from webmaster panel?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your webmaster tools sitemaps dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't always add all the pages in a site to it's index, creating a sitemap doesn't guarantee inclusion, rank or anything else.

So the issue isn't your crawl rate, it's that Google isn't ***yet*** interested in all your pages, it may choose to get interested in the future!

Comment: +1 ...and to address the other bit, there's no way to tell Google to crawl your sitemap any more or less often. The items in the sitemap itself can contain suggestions for how often to crawl each URL, but those are only suggestions.